# How to unit test a directive which opens a modal window

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Here is my directive

```
.directive('loginWindow',['$modal','$alert',function($modal,$alert){
        return{
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                var modal = $modal({ template: '../views/login/login.html',show:false});
                var alert = undefined;
                scope.$on('auth-invalid-user', function(event,invalidStatus) {
                    modal.show();
                    alert =  $alert({content: invalidStatus, type: 'danger', show: true,container:'#invalid-credential'});
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

I would like to unit test this directive, which opens a modal window(used Angular-strap) when an event is broadcast.How can I test whether `modal.show()` is been called.

I tried using a spy on `$modal` service but it didn't worked.

Can anyone help me to test this directive.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly didn't work with spy?

Comment: I tried like spyOn($modal,'show'). And I expected to show should have been called. But I think its wrong, since $modal is a provider and an instance of the $modal will have show function.